# SQL how alter output data name?

Tags: sql, oracle

Thursday and Friday I have my first out of two SQL courses planned so I am trying to prepare my knowledge a bit in advance. I would like to change the output when the cell of PR.BEW_STATUS has a '0'for example that it would give me text i gave the '0', Entering in this case.

I will be doing an Excel export of the data and instead of having like 300 '0' followed by 200 '1' etc I would like to show Entering etc. Is this possible and is this even easily achievable?

Many many thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've updated my entire code. I've been trying to insert the CASE in multiple ways but it will not work. Is this a more basic or more advanced SQL option?

```
SELECT 

PR.PRE_INV_ID "Pre-Stamkaart",
PI.INVENTARISNR "Inventaris",
PR.NAAM "Naam",
PR.MODEL "Model",
PR.TYPENR "Type",
PR.FABRIKAAT "Fabrikant",
PR.AANMAAK_DATUM "Aanmaak Datum",
PR.BEW_STATUS "Status"


FROM 

PRESTAMKAART PR,
PRESTAMKAART_INV PI 


WHERE 

PR.PRE_INV_ID = PI.PRE_INV_ID 
 
--Status van de verwerking van de algemene invoer, 0=Invoeren pre-stamkaart, 1=Klaar voor definitief, 2=gestart definitief maken, 5=geparkeerd, 9=afgehandeld
    AND PR.BEW_STATUS IN ('0','1','2','5') 
    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INVENTARIS I WHERE PI.INVENTARISNR = I.INVENTARISNR) 


Order BY PR.PRE_INV_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood it, it is `select`'s *responsibility*. If you have a table which holds explanation of those codes, `join` it, e.g.

```
select d.description, ...
from your_table a join desc_table d on d.bew_status = a.bew_status
where a.bew_status in ('0', '1', '2', '5')
```

---

Otherwise, `case` might help:

```
select case when a.bew_status = '0' then 'Entering'
            when a.bew_status = '1' then 'Ready'
            when a.bew_status = '2' then 'Started'    -- and so forth
       end as description
from your_table a
where a.bew_status in ('0', '1', '2', '5')
```

---

**[EDIT]** Your query might look like this; I added `case` expression and switched to `JOIN` (instead of tables listed in `FROM` clause and joined in `WHERE` which should be used for *conditions*, not *joins*):

```
SELECT pr.pre_inv_id       "pre-stamkaart",
       pi.inventarisnr     "inventaris",
       pr.naam             "naam",
       pr.model            "model",
       pr.typenr           "type",
       pr.fabrikaat        "fabrikant",
       pr.aanmaak_datum    "aanmaak datum",
       pr.bew_status       "status",
       --
       CASE
         WHEN a.bew_status = '0' THEN 'Entering'
         WHEN a.bew_status = '1' THEN 'Ready'
         WHEN a.bew_status = '2' THEN 'Started'    -- and so forth
       END AS description
FROM prestamkaart pr JOIN prestamkaart_inv pi ON pr.pre_inv_id = pi.pre_inv_id 
--Status van de verwerking van de algemene invoer, 0=Invoeren pre-stamkaart, 1=Klaar voor definitief, 2=gestart definitief maken, 5=geparkeerd, 9=afgehandeld
WHERE pr.bew_status IN('0', '1', '2', '5')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM inventaris i
              WHERE pi.inventarisnr = i.inventarisnr
             )
ORDER BY pr.pre_inv_id;
```

Comment: I've been trying to incorporate CASE since that is indeed what I would like but I cannot get it to work with the rest of my commands. Maybe I am looking too long at it and not seeing the obvious anymore. I could post the entire sql command but I don't feel too comfortable just throwing it out there.

Comment: I can't tell anything about it either. It is difficult to debug code you can't see, or give advice about errors / problems that aren't described. As it won't cost much, edit the original question and post code you have, as well as error you get (if any, or describe what "I cannot get it to work" means) so we'll have a look and, possibly, help.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that makes a lot sense! I've editted my post, been trying different ways to incorporate the CASE but it will not work. PR.BEW_STATUS "Status" now shows 0, 1, 2 or 5. I would like that to show what you already described: Entering, Ready, Started etc...

Comment: You're welcome; I edited my answer and added code that - I hope - will work. Can't test it, I don't have your tables.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try it first thing tommorow morning! :D

Comment: No problem at all :)